# Electron app does not function properly after built into an exe file

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I have just finished working on a test project in electron. The problem is that when I package the app using an electron-packager into an executable, my main.html file does not load up in the window.
However, when I run with `npm start` it works absolutely fine. I have checked if there is any mistake in the path to my files but that's absolutely fine as well.

Here's my package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Just a test app",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Ray",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('./app/main.html')
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should start accepting answers that are given if they did help, or react somehow if it did not help. If you just asking questions and play dead afterwards nobody can learn from your Questions and people will stop answering them.

Comment: Sorry. I had taken a long break from programming. I ended up deleting the project and recreating it. It works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `electron-packager`should be part of devDependencies, not dependencies.

Second: How do you pack? If you use an asar File you need to look at the Paths. Those change when packing. So I'd recommend you use something like

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main.html`)
```

or

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'main.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

when loading your html.